# Unexpected method call meaning in EasyMock/PowerMock

Tags: junit, powermock, easymock

I am pretty confused with the error "Unexpected method call" in PowerMock/EasyMock.
Let me know in which one of the below two scenario the above error refers to.

1. I have an written an expectation for a method and the method is not available in the actual code.
2. I have not written an expectation in junit for a method which is present in the actual code.

Comment: It is #2. You don't have written an expectation for a methods that is actually executed in your test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means your mocked object received an unexpected method call (option 2 in your question).

To resolve this, you need to write an expectation that allows this invocation (or correct your application code if this method shouldn't be called).